# Probability of balls entering boxes

Tags: binomial-distribution, balls-in-bins

I had some troubles with the following exercise:

**Randomly throw 5 balls into one of the 4 boxes. What is the probability that no boxes are empty?**

I think the answer is P(A) = 4 * (5!/1!*1!*1!*2!) * (1/4)^5. (I multiply by 4 because I believe it can happen in 4 different ways)

My question is if the question asked about the probability of having 3 empty box. Would it be
P(A) = 4 * (5!/5!) * (1/4)^5

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your answer to the 2nd question - re 3 empty boxes, there are only 4 ways that it can happen, so chances are $$\frac{4}{4^5} = \frac{1}{4^4}.$$

For the 1st question, I can't tell if we agree because you didn't use mathJax.  So, I'll just explain my reasoning and post my computation.

Again, the denominator is $$\frac{1}{4^5}.$$

There are 4 ways you can select which box gets 2 balls.

Assume Box 1 will be the box with two balls.

Now, there are 5 choices for which ball went into Box 4. 
With that decided, there are 4 choices for which ball went into Box 3. 
Then there are 3 choices for which ball went into Box 2.

So the numerator is $4 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 = 240.$

Final answer is $$\frac{240}{4^5} = \frac{15}{4^3}.$$